# I am using Tweepy, but It got stuck at one tweet. It keep sleeping at one specific tweet and repeating this process

Tags: tweepy

I am collecting tweets using Tweepy. I have 500 Tweet ids and try to collect 3200 recent tweets from each tweet_id. The below is my code. but the problem is that it doesn't move but stuck at some tweet that I am trying to collect.. On my termial, It keep iterating show me that

'''
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 600
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
...1545 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 1117195540448432127
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 644
'''
So I think there must be exception occurered when I am trying to collect tweet from user: halfbare..? but I really don't know how to handle this... Can Anyone help me please?

Code:

```
import tweepy
import csv

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):


    consumer_key = *
    consumer_secret = * 
    access_key = *
    access_secret = *

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets & list with no retweets
    alltweets = []
    noRT = []

    #make initial request for most recent tweets with extended mode enabled to get full tweets
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, tweet_mode = 'extended', count=200, include_retweets=False)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until the api limit is reached
    while len(alltweets) <= 3200:
        print("getting tweets before {}".format(oldest))

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,tweet_mode = 'extended', count=200,max_id=oldest, include_retweets=False)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print("...{} tweets downloaded so far".format(len(alltweets)))

        #removes retweets
    for tweet in alltweets:
        if 'RT' in tweet.full_text:
            continue
        else:
            noRT.append([tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode("utf-8")])

            #, tweet.user, tweet.coordinates, tweet.place

    #write to csv
    with open('{}_tweets.csv'.format(screen_name), 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(noRT)
        print('{}_tweets.csv was successfully created.'.format(screen_name))
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
        #pass in the username of the account you want to download
        usernames = ["halfbare","Huw_Merlin"]
        #"Fla_Medic","GertvanderHoek",
        for x in usernames:
            get_all_tweets(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears only for the user "halfbare" in your list. This is because this user has tweeted less then 3200 tweets.
You can check this with:

```
user = api.get_user("halfbare") 
statuses_count = user.statuses_count
```

When all the user's tweets have been collected, the len(alltweets) in your while loop does not increase anymore (as there are no more tweets to add for this user) so the while condition is always true.
You should add a break condition in the while loop, after retrieving the new_tweets:

```
if len(new_tweets) == 0:
                break
```